# Can hashcodes be compared with <= => signs?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've come across a piece of code in dart

```
id.hashCode <= peerId.hashCode
```

I understand the check `==` But how does a less than or greater than work with hashcodes. The console just prints out different numbers. What do these number represent to make them comparable by `<=` and `>=`

**EDIT:- Adding Context to Question **
The use case is to facilitate 2 users writing to the same node in firestore by hashing the users `Firebase uid's`and creating a string like this

```
if (currentId.hashCode <= peerId.hashCode) {
    groupChatId = '$currentId-$peerId';
} else {
    groupChatId = '$peerId-$currentId';
}
```

Just making use of the fact the `hashcode` is an `integer` and unique

Comment: `hashCode` can technically be a random number. It has no meaning, so while you can use `<=` & `>=`, this makes very little sense.

Comment: here's a reason @RémiRousselet

Comment: `and unique` hashcodes are not unique.

Comment: I was going through his article, https://medium.com/flutter-community/building-a-chat-app-with-flutter-and-firebase-from-scratch-9eaa7f41782e, and this technique is used in there, I just dont understand how this works either

Comment: I had a eureka moment and hence have shared the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hashcode in flutter is really just an integer. So when you compare a hash code to a hashcode with < or > what you are doing is comparing whether the integer value of one hash code is larger than the other. I can't think of any actual use for this as hashcodes are typically used to verify that an object is exactly what you want.

Depending on the implementation of calculating the hashcode there could be some meaning to one hashcode being larger than another but I can't think of any real world use cases that would benefit from using a hashcode rather than the specific property you would want to compare.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing this question is in relation to this article https://medium.com/flutter-community/building-a-chat-app-with-flutter-and-firebase-from-scratch-9eaa7f41782e . I had the same question as OP, I had a eureka moment and hence sharing what I got.

The `hashCode` property simply returns a number like this [image]. So lets say two users `A` and `B` are chatting, so inorder to fetch messages between A(eg, hashCode=11) and B(eg, hashCode=22), this has to be stored in the same firestore collection, for that we need a unique id(`groupChatId`). If we were to create `groupChatId`(here groupChatId is used as the key for the firestore collection) simply by `'$curentId-$peerId'` `groupChatId` would be `11-22` for A and `22-11` for B, which would result in two collections. Instead if we use the logic of:

```
if (currentId.hashCode <= peerId.hashCode) {
   groupChatId = '$currentId-$peerId';
} else {
   groupChatId = '$peerId-$currentId';
}
```

`groupChatId` will be `11-22` for both A and B, hence the same firestore collection can be used to write and read from.